# Converting special object to Dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

For `y.Value as Excelwert` I get `null`.

My code:

```
Dictionary<String, List<Excelwert>> kernListe = myList.Where(x => x.Key.Equals(nameDerList))
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => { return new List<Excelwert>(){ y.Value as Excelwert}; });
```

`myList` is `Dictionary<string,object>`.

[This](http://s32.postimg.org/j1rpat63p/problem_With_Converting.png) is how the `Value`looks like in my watch.

What shall I change ?

Comment: Please post your code instead of links to images.  It's so much easier to copy and past than take a screen shot.  I just don't understand.

Comment: return new List<object>

Comment: updated post again. @Uthistran S. this did not work.

Comment: Sounds like the values aren't actually `Excelwert` references. It' not clear why you're creating single-element lists anyway, mind you...

Comment: @Jon Skeet , converting `(y.Value as List<object>)` will result in [that](http://s32.postimg.org/u221fc2p1/problem_With_Converting.png)...

Comment: I didn't suggest doing that, and it doesn't explain why you're creating single entry lists. It's unclear what you're trying to achieve, I'm afraid - and likewise all we can really tell is that the values in the oddly-named `myList` aren't references to `Excelwert` objects. Try posting a [mcve] and give more information about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: "y.Value as Excelwert": If y is not an Excelwert, it will be null. I guess your myList object may not be a list of Excelwert's?

Comment: y.Value is not Excelwert, as looking at your screenshot it has different values for each item. I assume you didn't override `.ToString()` method.